# How do I work out what version of IntelliJ a particular version of Android Studio is based on?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

How do I work out what version of IntelliJ a particular version of Android Studio is based on? I had a look in the "About Android Studio" window and all I see is the following information:

[image: Screenshot of the About Android Studio window]

Comment: The link to `open-source software` is a good source, though it doesn't specifically mention which version was used to produce the "release" version that you're seeing, it does give you an insight of the actual dependencies they use. Alternatively the [preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/) version of Android Studio tends to show the Intellij-IDEA version used (and I imagine this doesn't arbitrarily change unless major Android Studio release happens).

Comment: (interestingly enough, Google doesn't seem to say this in the actual release notes for each stable version, or if they do, they do it "once" and it's hard to find, but perhaps I'm not looking hard enough) ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help @MartinMarconcini. I've found the answer. I'll post it shortly.

Comment: Somebody has helpfully posted an answer so I don't have to 

Comment: Ahh I'm gonna say "TIL" but now that I read this, I recall having read this before... but apparently I have completely forgotten about it so thanks for the reminder ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first three groups of numbers of the Android Studio build are the version of the IntelliJ Platform build that the Android Studio build is based on: 213.7172.25. The first two digits indicate the year: 2021. The third digit indicates the release number: 3. So it is based on the 2021.3 version of the IntelliJ Platform.

See also: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/build-number-ranges.html#build-number-format

Answer (score 2):

The Android Studio version name (e.g. "2021.3.1") encodes what version of IntelliJ it was based on, as follows:

```
<Year of IntelliJ Version>.<IntelliJ major version>.<Studio major version>
```

As described in the "New versioning scheme - Android Studio" section of the [Announcing Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) & Android Gradle plugin 7.0](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/12/announcing-android-studio-arctic-fox.html) Android Developers Blog post:

> - The first two number groups represent the version of the final IntellIj platform that a particular Android Studio release is based on (earlier canaries may still be on the earlier version). For this release, this is 2020.3.
> - The third number group represents the Studio major version, starting at 1 and incrementing by one for every major release.

So "2021.3.1", for example, encodes that this version of Android Studio is based on the "2021.3" version of the IntelliJ platform.